# Installing oracle-database-preinstall-21c - Oracle Linux

Tags: oracle-linux, oracle-database

I am completely new to Linux world.  I am following a course in udemy and trying to install the oracle database on oracle Linux 9.1.  One of the prerequisites is to run the below command

```
dnf install oracle-database-preinstall-18c
```

But I am getting the error

> No match for argument: oracle-database-preinstall-21c
>
> Error: Unable to find a match: oracle-database-preinstall-21c

Comment: Follow the steps from [this site](https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/oracle-db-21c-rpm-installation-on-oracle-linux-8). I've not tested yet but it might work.